# (Done) Reopen: Messy code from co-worker

Tags: discussion, reopen-request

[This question](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/120123/how-to-cope-with-a-code-messy-coworker) was recently closed as lacking a goal we could address.

I've edited the question and tried to state a clear, answerable goal that would would resolve the OP's issue.

Answer (score 3):

*Update:* Post is open again now.

---

Good edit! It made the question answerable and on-topic.

I casted the 4th vote to reopen...